# PHP 7.0 Segmentation fault when reading memcached

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron, memcached

I use Laravel 5.5 with memcached 1.4.21. In front : nginx server (1.10.1) and a fpm process PHP 7.0.

Cron task use the same model than web controller. But when cron accede to memcached, the process crash with a **Segmentation fault**. The same code work like a charme from a HTTP request. The only difference it's that cron use PHP CLI and web controller use fpm process.

Sometimes I have also this error message :

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mybase.onefield' doesn't exist

Yes "mybase.onefield", Eloquent try to use one table field in place of my table name.

I have problem only on production server. Do you have any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After focus on memcached access problem, I searched the difference with pre-production configuration server and I find one : igbinary version.

On pre-production :

```
--> php -i | grep igbinary
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-igbinary.ini,                                                                       
igbinary                                                                                                                                       
igbinary support => enabled                                                                                                                    
igbinary version => 2.0.1
```

On production :

```
--> php -i | grep igbinary
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-igbinary.ini,                                                                       
igbinary                                                                                                                                       
igbinary support => enabled                                                                                                                    
igbinary version => 1.2.2-dev
```

igbinary manage serialization of object store into memcached.
After update igbinary, all work well.

The command that save my life :

```
apt-get install php7.0-igbinary
```

Comment: Just a friendly reminder: You can accept your own answer, that will mark the question as answered then (I know that you have to wait a day or so).